# How can $e^{-i\omega t}$ be simplified when normalizing a wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

I'm going through some of the practice problems in a QM textbook. (This isn't a homework question, I'm not taking a class.)

When normalizing the wavefunction
$$\Psi= Ae^{-\lambda |x|}e^{-i\omega t}$$

He does the squaring as usual and simplifies $e^{-2i\omega t} = 2$. I've played around with Euler's formula and can't figure out how it is done. Any secret tricks or something?

$$1=\int|\Psi|^2dx=2|A|^2\int_0^\infty e^{-2\lambda x}dx$$

Comment: Over what interval is the wave function defined and normalized? Is it from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, $0$ to $\infty$, or something else?

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematics - it is the site standard.

Comment: I found some more information from a youtube video. The original bounds of the integral were from -infinity to +infinity, but because the wavefunction was the |x|, in the solutions he substituted by changing the bounds of the integral to 0 to +infinity, and multiplying the integral by 2. So I guess that e^-iwt simply goes to 1 and it was my misunderstanding.

Comment: The phase factor $e^{-i\omega t}$ cancels in the absolute square. The factor of two comes from changing the integration limits, but the integrand has to be an even function of x for that to work. Are you sure it's not $e^{-\lambda x^2}$?

Comment: Yes, I corrected the wavefunction to show the absolute value, sorry Nick. Thank you for the clarification about the phasor factor.

Comment: $\psi^*$ has a $e^{i\omega t}$ factor.

Comment: @MFerguson I'd recommend editing what you had tried into the question, to show that you've done more thinking about the problem.

Comment: It's not "squaring as usual", it's taking the [norm of a complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to note:

1. The wave function is, in this case, defined on the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$. This means that when you normalize it, you integrate from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.
2. The notation $|\Psi|$ just means that you're taking the magnitude of the wave function. For instance, for a complex number in the form $Ae^{i\theta}$, the magnitude is just $A$, because the magnitude of $e^{i\theta}$ is taken to be $1$ for real values of $\theta$. We get this from multiplying the wave function by its complex conjugate.

Putting these together, we have, in full,
$$1=\int |\Psi|^2dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|Ae^{-l|x|}e^{-i\omega t}|^2dx$$
Now, we said that $|e^{-i\omega t}|=1$, so this is just
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|Ae^{-l|x|}e^{-i\omega t}|^2dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|Ae^{-l|x|}|^2dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}A^2e^{-2l|x|}dx\tag{1}$$
Now, the wave-function is symmetric in $x$ - that is, $\Psi(-x)=\Psi(x)$. We should really rewrite it, to make this clearer:
$$\Psi(x)=
\begin{cases}
Ae^{lx} && x<0\\
Ae^{-lx} && x >0
\end{cases}
$$
Let's break up the final integral in $(1)$:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}A^2e^{-2l|x|}dx=\int_{-\infty}^0A^2e^{2lx}dx+\int_0^{\infty}A^2e^{-2lx}dx$$
Can you go from here, and see where the factor of $2$ comes in?

Comment: Thanks for the help, my confusion has been dissolved. :^)